# Change multiple checkbox values

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have 2 forms. The second form (frmConvert) has 3 checkboxes. I can change the value of one checkbox by using :-

Form1

```
f.CheckBoxChecked = true;
```

(frmConvert)

```
public bool CheckBoxChecked
{
get { return checkBox1.Checked; }
set { checkBox1.Checked = value; }
}
```

What I'd like to know is, if I have 3 checkboxes (checkBox1, checkBox2 & checkBox3), how can I have a seperate line of code on form1 so I can change the value of each seperately, without having seperate functions for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do

```
public void doCheck(int index,bool value)
    {

        switch (index)
        {
            case 1:
                checkBox1.Checked = value;
                break;
            case 2:
                checkBox2.Checked = value;
                break;
            case 3:
                checkBox3.Checked = value;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

and use :

```
Form3 f = new Form3();
f.doCheck(2, true);
f.doCheck(3, false);
f.ShowDialog();
```